# Can I refer my sibling for a PhD position under my supervisor? How should I approach this?

Tags: graduate-admissions, supervision, canada

I am an international student who is completing a master's degree. I am very happy working with my professor at the university. I am a good student. My professor and I have some successful projects and publications.
My sibling is looking for a Ph.D. position, and since my professor is a very reliable person, I would like him to start a Ph.D. under my professor's supervision at the same school.

He told us to introduce good students to him. I am wondering if it would be awkward if I directly ask my professor to hire him as a Ph.D. student. If so, how should I ask him? What is the best approach? Is it ok to ask this?

Comment: Also note that recommending someone who then doesn't perform well can have negative consequences for you. These might be worse if people think you tried sneaking an unqualified relative in. Plus, if your sibling and your professor don't get along, this could impact your relationship with your sibling. I'm not advising against it, but think it through prior to doing it.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it all the existing answers are based on the fact that you ask about recommending a sibling and not just “someone”. If you accidentally used the word *sibling* and noticed that this question does not reflect your situation, please ask a new question, as this one is valid as it is and useful for others.

Answer (score 22):

I would worry a bit about asking the professor to "hire" your sibling. On the other hand, telling the professor that your sib is looking for a position in the same field and would like to meet them to talk about the possibilities would be entirely appropriate.

If the two of them, without you, come to some understanding it would be better. And even if that isn't possible, the prof may have some good ideas for your sibling to pursue.

So, I'd suggest a somewhat less direct approach.

Answer (score 9):

According to your question, your professor has specifically asked you to introduce good students to him, so if you think your sibling fits this criteria (and you evidently do) then you should feel free to introduce your sibling to the professor.  I see no reason why that would need to be awkward.

In terms of how to go about this, *don't ask your professor to hire your sibling* (that is extremely presumptuous); just introduce them and let things go from there.  You can introduce them, but your sibling will need to do the work to interest your professor.  From your perspective, the easiest thing here would be to frame this as a response to your professor's request ---e.g., "You mentioned earlier that you are interested in having us refer any good students we know to you.  My [brother/sister] is a strong student in [subject] and is looking for positions in a PhD program.  Would you mind meeting with [him/her] to see if [he/she] is a good fit for your research group."

Answer (score 1):

In Academia, seeking employment for a relative (nepotism) is considered a bad behavior.  I suggest you don't ask for your relative to be hired.

The exception is that, when you have been offered a job but not accepted it yet, you may ask for a job for your relative (typically a spouse) as part of employment negotiations.  This is rarely successful, and in some places universities cannot legally hire certain relatives.

Your sibling should use the usual PhD application process for your university.

Comment: This assumes PhD students are paid, as is typical; universities are quite happy to take on your tuition-paying relatives.